# How to build GTK GUI application as I want?

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

Recently I started to have a look at the GTK library in C, and wanted to create GUI application. In fact, I want to create an image application, but I don't know how to make my application looking exactly the same as my drawing, I've looked throught the gtk3-demo and also the widget factory but problems remains;
How to create GUI application, how do I know which container should I use, how do I know what kind of widget ? etc... So I have a picture of what I want to do, but I have absolutly no idea how. What is the process, what question should I ask myself in order to get my GUI application done ? [Drawing of my application link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGRmc.png)

Comment: The short answer: experiment. The best way might be to just install the Glade application, which is the UI builder for GTK. You can then see how each widget work. https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Glade/

Comment: About the container, don't bother and just use GtkGrid, available in GTK+ 3. You probably don't need the other containers unless you're doing something very special.

Comment: I'll add [GtkWidget Gallery](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch03.html) from the reference API. [Gnome User interface Guidelines](https://developer.gnome.org/hig/stable/) (HIG) also has some interesting tips if your goal is to create a GNOME application. Some [beginner tutorials](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/c.html.en) are also available from GNOME.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, I think i'm starting to figure out how Glade layout and the other components are working, and it's better to have a quick preview of what your app looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would very much recommend you play with the Gtk3 GUI using python. You can interactively create windows, containers. Even later, it is much faster to develop the GUI in python, as many have already experienced.

Most of the Gtk3 C/C++ tutorials are available in Python too.

Glade is excellent in many cases - particularly if you want only standard behaviour of the widgets. If you even slightly wander from that straight path, things can get complicated quickly.

If it is really necessary, there are several ways to incorporate C/C++  functions into the Python GUI to make those critical apps go faster.

Comment: `Most of the Gtk3 C/C++ tutorials are available in Python too.` I'll put it in the comments yet, so everybody sees it for sure.

Comment: @theGtknerd Yes I admit that Python is maybe really good for Gtk, but I really need to do it in C/C++ as it's for "educational purposes", and I really want to get better in C/C++ so my choice is made, but, maybe, later, I will do things in Python, as you said, it's really fast

Comment: Great! I must admit I learned Gtk (it was a while ago...) in C... I even used Gtk 1.x then Gtk 2. I have many thousands of lines written using those Gtk versions! And I still use C to write speed-critical stuff (even assembler sometimes)..

Comment: I was trying to be funny by repeating what @jcoppens already said two times. You missed the joke, guys :P